# In EF GetById is of type T but I need a List?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

```
IGroupTypeRepository groupTypeRepo = new GroupTypeRepository();

IGroupRepository groupRepo = new GroupRepository();

var model = new GroupModels();
model.GroupTypeNames = groupTypeRepo.GetAll().ToList();
//now I want to show all group info group only 1st group type so used like following
Guid first = model.GroupTypeNames.FirstOrDefault().Id;
//in below code i can't simply do like groupRepo.GetById(first).ToList() as GetById is of T
//but its important to get all group values into model.GroupNames             
model.GroupNames = groupRepo.GetById(first);

return View("Groups", model);
```

How can i get all group values into `model.GroupNames` who's of no.1 group type.

Comment: So you're passing in an ID, which is typically a unique identifier, but you actually want a list? Something doesn't smell right here.

Comment: I'm passing a GUID of `group type` for example `.net group id` and i want a `list of all members` so that i can display that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Where` clause to do that instead of using `GetById` as following.It will return the list of matched

```
model.GroupNames = groupRepo.GetAll().Where(s=>s.GroupTypeID==first).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work (change SomeProperty to your actually property name):

```
model.GroupNames = groupRepo.GetAllGroups().Where(x=>x.SomeProperty==first).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing something like this.

```
model.GroupNames=groupRepo.GetAllGroups(s=>s.GroupTypeID==first).toList();
```

Assuming `GetAllGroups` method in your repositary returns a collection of `Group` and each Group has a Property called `GroupTypeID` which you want to use for filtering. Also the above code assumes that the `GroupNames` property of your model is of type, a collection of `Group`.